# Is it possible to find how much time someone spends on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I've noticed Instagram (and Facebook) have made activity-tracking data more accessible to users for moderation purposes... See [this article](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2018/08/206008/instagram-time-spent-reminder).
Is it possible to see other people's activity data, and does one need an Instagram account to do so?
Is the same possible with Facebook?

This might allow me to help my friend out with her addictions to social media.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you will not be able to do that for privacy reasons, something Facebook has been under fire for a few times. The only way is for you to have access to your friend's account and view such data from there.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable. Thank you for your answer. 

Answer (score 0):

Edit after OP's comment:
You can't see other's account data or any details which is meant for personal use due to security reasons.

You can ask your friend to follow the below steps in his/her account and then you can show how much time they are spending.

From [Instagram help page](https://help.instagram.com/195902884574087?helpref=related):

> **How do I see how much time I've spent on Instagram?**
>
> You can see the average amount of time you spent on Instagram within the last 7 days. Time spent on Instagram starts when you open the app, and ends when you close it or switch to using another app on your device.
>
> To see how much time you've spent on Instagram:
>
> > **Instagram app for Android and iPhone:**
> >
> > 1. Tap your profile picture in the bottom right to go to your profile.
> > 2. Tap Menu (three horizontal line top right).
> > 3. Tap **Your Activity**, then tap **Time**. You'll see the average time you spent on Instagram in the last week.
>
> You can [set a reminder](https://help.instagram.com/2049425491975359) to let you know when you've spent a certain amount of time on Instagram.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, with all due respect, this is not what has been asked. I think there was a misunderstanding. The initial question was how to find someone else's time spent on Instagram, not one's own. It might have been a lack of precision from my part, sorry.

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the step-by-step instructions.